# Игра в угадывание(Head First Java)

Tags: java

Новичок начал изучать Head First Java столкнулся с проблемой что код используемый в этой книге устарел, помогите довести задачу до рабочего состояния)

```
public class GuessGame {
    public static void main(System[] args) {
        Player p1; //ругается на этом моменте
        Player p2; //ругается на этом моменте
        Player p3; //ругается на этом моменте

        public void startGame(){
            p1 = new Player();
            p2 = new Player();
            p3 = new Player();

            int guessp1 = 0;
            int guessp2 = 0;
            int guessp3 = 0;

            boolean p1isRight = false;
            boolean p2isRight = false;
            boolean p3isRight = false;

            int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("Я загадываю число от 0 до 9...");

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Число, которое нужно угадать, - " + targetNumber);

                p1.guess();
                p2.guess();
                p3.guess();

                guessp1 = p1.number;
                System.out.print("Первый игрок думает, что это " + guessp1);
                guessp2 = p2.number;
                System.out.print("Первый игрок думает, что это " + guessp2);
                guessp3 = p3.number;
                System.out.print("Первый игрок думает, что это " + guessp3);

                if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                    p1isRight = true;
                }
                if (guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                    p2isRight = true;
                }
                if (guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                    p3isRight = true;
                }

                if (p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                    System.out.println("У нас есть победитель!");
                    System.out.println("Первый игрок угодал?" + p1isRight);
                    System.out.println("Второй игрок угодал?" + p2isRight);
                    System.out.println("Третий игрок угадал?" + p3isRight);
                    System.out.print("КОнец игры.");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Игроки должны попробовать еще раз.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код не устарел, вы невнимательно читаете книгу.

Answer (score 2):

Код не устарел. Я не читал "Head First Java" и не знаю, внятно ли там сказано, что каждая переменная должна относится к какому-то типу, а этот тип должен быть либо предопределенным типом Java, либо классом, определенным в вашем коде. Java -- это строго-типизированный язык.
У вас описываются переменные `p1, p2, p3` типа `Player` (строки, на которые ругается компилятор), но тип Player не описан в вашем коде и не является стандартным типом `Java`. Читайте книгу внимательнее, там рядом, скорее всего, есть еще один кусок кода, где описан тип `Player`. 
И чтобы лучше понимать основные концепции языка, есть смысл почитать и другие книги по `Java`.
И кстати, когда компилятор ругается, читайте его (компилятора) сообщения. Иногда они настолько точно и ясно указывают на ошибку, что не возникает нужды задавать дополнительные вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.print("Первый игрок думает, что это " + guessp2);` - первый замените на второй и третий.

У вас метод `startGame()` находится в `main()`. Вынесите его в отдельный метод.

Рабочий код:

```
public static void main(System[] args) { starGame(); }
        public void startGame(){
            p1 = new Player();
            p2 = new Player();
            p3 = new Player();
            ...
            }
```

Так же у вас должен быть определен класс Player.

Answer (score 0):

[image: :)]

На следующей странице посмотри :)